# Defending against 100-year flood

Tags: natural-disasters, infrastructure, protection

The city I'm designing had a 100-year flood in the year 1907. The city has a population of 90,000 inhabitants and is situated on a confluence of two navigable rivers.

River "Q" is about 400m wide; it has significant wetlands (about 200 to 400m on each bank) which absorb the more frequent flooding events. River "V" (which flows into "Q") is only 200m wide without protection. The city is a provincial capital with significant commerce and industry.

The "flooding event" had the waters rise 10ft (3m) above the normal water level. This flooded 40% to 50% of the built-up area.

My on-line research only yielded that the term '100-year flood' is misleading. It actually means a 1% probability of such event happening in that given year. Those odds increase to 63% in any 100-year period. I also read most of the report from the UK flood of London in 2001 or there about. None of these sources answer my question.

Further 'technical' information: Planet is earth-like, with earth gravity, physics and size. There is no magic, city is on an latitude of 9*30'S, The city is over 2000 km from the ocean, The city is about half-way down the course of the river; The source is glacial from a 30,000 ft peak, (Roughly equatorial). City is in an unexplained natural jungle clearing few hundred km in either direction. Farmers took advantage of this fact and grow their crops / livestock there. Relatively flat terrain, with the 20ft elevation line being between 600 to 1000m from the bank.

**The question is: Do I protect the city against this event with infrastructure?**

[image: Very low resolution image of Vaenesston]

Comment: What do you mean with the second question? As far as I know nobody has ever been glad to be flooded...

Comment: I know nobody wants to be flooded. What I'm trying to ask is "Oh, we need to build levees now", or "Well, its a rare act of God, little we can do about it", or "$#!t happens, mop-up and move on".

Comment: @L.Dutch: Not _quite_ true. The ancient Egyptians waited for the Nile to flood, as it saved them irrigation for the year.

Comment: @GregWochlik: It depends entirely on who's affected: if the ruling groups are harmed then, "Oh, we need to build levees now". If it's just the plebs, then the latter reactions.

Comment: @nzaman, true, but they didn't build houses in the likely to be flooded areas

Comment: I am looking for the attitudes of the officials who genuinely care about their people. They need to balance the risk against financial costs. As for who got flooded: all 5 classes (poor, low-income, med-income, high income, rich).

Comment: Dutch started building their protection against floods well before 1907, and protecting your land (especially when you live there too) from disasters like floods is the ABC of ruling classes. I think you can remove the second question.

Comment: If your city sits in the middle of a sparsely populated plain hundreds of kilometers wide the most common approach is to make a [flood control channel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_control_channel) to divert the floodwater elsewhere.

Comment: The first several times I glanced at this title and thought is asked "Defending against 100-year food."  Very different question...

Comment: If you were to provide visual details (a map) and ask how best to protect the town I think that could easily fall under *city-design* but as it stands you are just asking if someone should build to defend against a very rare event...which is plain old opinion based.

Comment: Why is this Worldbuilding?  It belongs to either engineering, or to psychology if you're asking why people build in flood-prone areas and do or don't build protections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flood protection must be looked at as a long term investment.

So basically, what is the principal cost of the protection, and what is the ongoing annual maintenance cost, versus what is the probable losses to all if the project is not undertaken (or equivalently the probable replacement cost of what would be ruined).

The latter should be projected into the foreseeable future: Levees built now may protect future development, buildings, roads, farms, residences and businesses that may not exist now but are in the planning stages.

You do not have to get too sophisticated in this estimate; most investments are not made if a rough calculation does not show clear and convincing future returns.

So just compute the cold-hearted monetary value of what would be destroyed by the flood if it happened today. Would 1% of that value be more than double what it would cost to protect it? (I mean the for real cost, not some politically deceptive low-ball cost that will be inflated five fold to cover the payoffs and overruns.)

If so, tax the assets to be protected and build the levees. Just like real investment analysts, you can ignore all the other analysis of whether this is good or bad for the economy, creates or destroys jobs, etc.

The "investors" here (albeit coerced) are the citizens with property to be protected; we are talking about their money and how to most likely maximize it over the long term by taking action to reduce their probable expenses. That is all that *rationally* matters.

Political ego and other cultural emotions may have an impact (most people dislike taxes, some people hate collective action like infrastructure even if it is the cheapest way, or **only** way, to accomplish something (e.g. nobody with a small house and garden could reasonably build levees to protect **just his own property**, they would occupy most of his land).

From an economic point of view, you want to assess for each course of action what the most likely net worth will be in 69 years (computation below). Take the action that leaves the largest net worth.

**Scenario 1:** We tax and spend the money to build levees and maintain them. Presuming the levees would protect us, it makes no difference if there is a flood; our net worth will be [Now - cost of levees - 69 years worth of maintenance on levees].

**Scenario 2:** We do not tax and spend the money to build or maintain levees. There is a 50 percent chance of a flood. Our net worth then will be [Now - 0.5*cost of all losses due to flood).

**69 years:**

Balances the probability of flood vs. no flood. If there is a 1% chance per year, there is a 99% chance of no flood. How many years before the odds of a flood are 50/50? Compute $\frac{\log(0.5)}{\log(0.99)}=68.9676$, so in the next 69 years there is a 50/50 chance of a 100-year flood occurring.

Answer (score 4):

## Model it after a real flood, and the measures taken after that.

**The city of Dayton, Ohio, flooded in 1913.**

> The Dayton flood of March 1913 was caused by a series of severe winter rain storms that hit the Midwest in late March. Within three days, 8–11 inches (200–280 mm) of rain fell throughout the Great Miami River watershed on already saturated soil, resulting in more than 90 percent runoff. The river and its tributaries overflowed. The existing levees failed, and downtown Dayton was flooded up to 20 feet (6.1 m) deep. This flood is still the flood of record for the Great Miami River watershed. By comparison, the volume of water that passed through the river channel during this storm equals the monthly flow over Niagara Falls.<sup>[source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Dayton_Flood)</sup>

*(There are markers on some buildings still standing that indicate where the flood waters reached. Seeing such markers on a second story of a building is... unsettling.)*

The source describes the flood timeline, the relief efforts, casualties, property damage, and of interest to you, the **flood control efforts** that began after this flood. The TL;DR version boils down to:

1. 10-day fundraiser (raised about $2 million in 1913 US dollars)
2. Hired engineers to conduct an analysis and design a plan
3. Borrowed from a plan used in Loire Valley in France
4. Began implementing a plan consisting of

   1. Five earthen dams
   2. modifications to river channel through Dayton
   3. conduits to release limited amounts of water from dams
   4. widened river channel with series of levees
   5. flood storage areas behind dams (used as farmland)
   6. Relocation of any businesses inside the river channel boundaries of a 1,000-year flood

Their design goal was to contain 140% of the 1913 flood waters.

This also required passing state laws to let local governments define conservancy districts for flood control, raise money for civil engineering through taxes, and use eminent domain to take land for dams, basins, and flood plains.

Comment: +1 for mentioning flood diverting tactics, letting the flood discharge its energy and water in unpopulated areas can be far more effective than levee. if the breach levee actually make flooding worse by concentrating it.  bleeding off the water is more costly but also more effective.

Answer (score 0):

Of course the city will build dikes to protect against flooding, it is well within their economic and technological capabilities to protect against once-every-100-years floods. Water management on the scale of single cities has been done since ancient times.

You'd do well to build one dike at the winter level of your river. That keeps the waters navigable even when the glacial melt water is lowest. Then you build a much bigger secondary dike at the summer river levels, when the glacial melt is highest. If you build this dike decently it can withstand your flood event, or you can build a third dike specificaly for your floods if they can predicted and are regular.

The space between the 1st and 2nd dike is excelent land for cattle to graze. If you build the 3rd dike the urban poor can live in between the 2nd and 3rd.

But realisticly 2 dikes should be enough to protect against even major floods. Building a third for such a rare event is unlikely. It's much easier to just make your second dike strong enough to withstand a flood.

Comment: dual-use of dikes make them easier to pay for (e.g. as city wall). And dont forget to use or create areas that are designed for flodding (maybe on the side of the river that is opposite to the city?)

Answer (score 0):

Water is a tricky devil, and will usually get its way.

Dikes and levees can temporarily stop flooding in a region by building up the riverbanks.

HOWEVER. Excess water will still come, and it has to go somewhere. Usually, that involves the flood being shifted *upstream* of the existing dikes/levees, which kinda stinks for anyone living in that area who just got shafted by a downstream construction project.

They are usually then motivated to build dikes, which shifts the problems upstream, where the residents build dikes, which shifts... you see where this is going.

Perhaps this will be fine for a 1-in-68 year flood, but I would assume the river would marginally overflow its banks more often than the flood described.

Dikes and levees may still be the best option, but be aware of the long-term costs involved.

Answer (score 0):

Until you mentioned the jungle it sounded a bit like my hometown. (Hint: don't build an Arch.) The founders here realized that right at the confluence of two big rivers was a bad place to build a a city, it was just too marshy. They chose a limestone rise a bit south of the confluance. Other small town along the Mississippi found they had to move uphill or face constant flooding.

Other answers covered levees. Your people will also need to handle water that falls within the city. Fill in standing ponds and low areas (they are a cholera risk anyway). If the water is higher outside the levees you may need to develop a pump system or a bucket brigade or the world's most amazing drainage system.

Comment: Don't worry about arches, they got a kind of a "Stature of Librety" at the point of convergence. She is facing east, and points with her hand towards the city up the convergant river.